# "requestFeature() must be called before adding content" master detail template

Tags: android, android-fragments

I started a new app with the master detail template.

When I try the app on my tablet, using the two-pane layout, it crashes with the exception in the title when I change orientation of the tablet.
This happens only if the detail fragment has content.

The crash is in `super.onCreate` line, I'm not even calling `requestFeature`, so it's not even my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);

    if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {
        // The detail container view will be present only in the
        // large-screen layouts (res/values-large and
        // res/values-sw600dp). If this view is present, then the
        // activity should be in two-pane mode.
        mTwoPane = true;

        // In two-pane mode, list items should be given the
        // 'activated' state when touched.
        ((ItemListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.item_list)).setActivateOnItemClick(true);
    }

 }
```

Stack trace:

```
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065): Process: com.manor.barcam, PID: 32065
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to  start activity ComponentInfo{com.manor.barcam/com.manor.barcam.ItemListActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3738)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:135)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:249)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:3298)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:63)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at com.manor.barcam.ItemListActivity.onCreate(ItemListActivity.java:54)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
 12-14 23:18:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(32065):   ... 12 more
```

How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Show where you are calling `requestFeature()`. Also, show the full stack trace.

Comment: Added stack trace, I'm not calling `requestFeature()`.

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue but can't figure out how come [AndroidBootstrap](https://github.com/AndroidBootstrap/android-bootstrap) doesn't seem to encounter the same issue even though using the same ActionBarCompat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same issue but it happened when the app was killed in the background by the OS. I traced the problem to ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java from appcompat where the requestWindowFeature() is called after super.onCreate:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (mHasActionBar) {
        // If action bar is requested by inheriting from the appcompat theme,
        // the system will not know about that. So explicitly request for an action bar.
        mActivity.requestWindowFeature(WindowCompat.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    }
    if (mOverlayActionBar) {
        mActivity.requestWindowFeature(WindowCompat.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    }
```

So I imported the appcompat from [git](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/) and changed the above code to call the super.onCreate() after .requestWindowFeature() which solved the problem.
Also submitted a bug report to [Google](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66120&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

Answer (score 3):

Neither of them solved my case. That's why i come up with a nasty workaround.

My app was crashing when the `android OS` kill my app after long time in background.

While debugging i find out that my app is crashing on 
`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

But it is crashing only when the `savedInstanceState` is not `null`.
And i need no any user inputs to be saved and repopulated. Hence i just make call to `super.onCreate(null)` if `savedInstanceState` is not `null`.

And my comment goes there before that line

```
  /*
            * This may be the wrong workaround!!!
            * It demands more research..
            * But for now, if it solves the problem, then it is a solution :D
            * */
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            super.onCreate(null);
        } else {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
```

Will be trying to find the appropriate solution to it.

Answer (score 2):

I've just seen this in one of my apps. In my case the culprit was a call to `getActivity().getActionBar()` in one of my fragments in `onCreate()`. This has the side effect of creating a contentView for you if one doesn't exist.

Moving that line to `onViewCreated()` solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try use `getSupportActionBar();` instead of `getActionBar();`

Comment: this works with ActionBarActivity better than all other suggestions here